# External flash for TouchGFX is not working

Tags: touchgfx

I have made a custom board for a TouchGFX application. I made an external loader, but the QSPI flash memory is not working properly.
Initially I did a test on QSPI flash and I could write and read data from it.
I can read and erase the Qspi with CubeProgrammer.
I modified the Linker script to add QSPI and specify memory region for ExtFlashSection, TextFlashSection, FontFlashSection in CubeIDE, but I get a hardfualt error.

Initialization

[image: 1]

During the debugging I figured hard fault error happens when I get to "tick();" inside "virtual void backPorchExited()".
This error does not happen when I do not modify the linker script file for adding external qspi flash.
I am still codeing in the super loop mode and am not using Free RTOS yet.
Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I was able to work around the problem by putting the font and the text in the internal memory. Since my project is done I'm back to try to solve this issue. Things that I have found out: reading out the external memory data matches the bin generated; therefore the problem has to be reading from the external flash during run time.